# Keeping country based locale folder in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

In my locales folder contains 2 folder now as :

`en` and `ch` ( english and chines ) works fine. But now I require to split the languages as by country. I prefer to keep the parent folder as `country` and `sub` folders as langue(s) like :

`UK => En` and `UK => ch` so, can i keep the no.of folder for according to their country and subfolders are no.of languages?

can any one help me to keep multiple counties with multiple languaes inside?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what addon do you use for translation? There are 2 popular choices.

Comment: simply I asking you, now I am trying to get translations like : `this.get('i18n').set('locale', "sg/en");` with subfolder, but it works fine like : `this.get('i18n').set('locale', "en");` - without sub folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [ember-i18n](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n) then you should seperate language and region by `-`. For example `en-gb`.

Then you place your translations in folders like `en`, `en-gb` and `en-us`. If you dont specify a translation in `en-gb/translations.js` it will fall back to `en/translatons.js`. Check [the tests for an example](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/tree/master/tests/dummy/app/locales).

If you want a different structure you probably can do this by manually loading the translations in an initializer and then pusing them to the service.